# Show <select> values in PartialView ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I migrate project from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core

I was having Partial view with two daropdowns

**So Controller method was like this**

```
 public ActionResult AddPeopleToProposal()
    {
        ViewBag.Worker = new SelectList(db.People, "Id", "FIO").ToList();
        ViewBag.Proposal = new SelectList(db.Proposals, "Id", "Id").ToList();
        return PartialView("AddPeopleToProposal");
    }
```

**And in View I was render it like this**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addPeopleToProposal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Добавить работника на заявку</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Action("AddPeopleToProposal", "Manage")
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
            <button type="button" id="peopleToProposalCreate" class="btn btn-primary">Создать</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And Partial View**

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Працівник</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Worker", null, "XXXX", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "peopleIdAdd" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Оберіть заявку</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Proposal", null, "XXXX", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "proposalIdAdd" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Коментар</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="commentVchasno" >
</div>
```

But as I know `@Html.Action` was depricated

I realize this in Core like this

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AddPeopleToProposal()
    {
        ViewData["Worker"] = new SelectList(_context.People, "Id", "FIO");
        ViewData["Proposal"] = new SelectList(_context.Proposals, "Id", "Id");
        return PartialView("Partials/AddPeopleToProposal");
    }
```

**And Partial View**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="col-form-label">Працівник</label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Worker"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="col-form-label">Оберіть заявку</label>
        <select  class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Proposal"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="col-form-label">Коментар</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="commentVchasno" >
    </div>

</form>
```

**And View from where I cal  Partial**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addPeopleToProposal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Добавить работника на заявку</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("Partials/AddPeopleToProposal")
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
            <button type="button" id="peopleToProposalCreate" class="btn btn-primary">Создать</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But at Core I don't have values in selects. Where is my problem?

Comment: I got caught out on this. You need to migrate to use `ViewComponents` for things like this. See: https://medium.com/@DomBurf/using-viewcomponents-in-asp-net-core-2-0-804171b660ac

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize the page directly when getting the Partial View, try to put the following two lines of code into the get request of the main View of the Partial View. [More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1) about Partial views

```
ViewData["Worker"] = new SelectList(_context.People, "Id", "FIO");
ViewData["Proposal"] = new SelectList(_context.Proposals, "Id", "Id");
```

Or you could use the [ViewComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instead of the Partial View to get the fill data of the dropdownlists from the Invoke method in the view component class. Try to the code like below

ViewComponent.cs

```
 public class AddPeopleToCountryViewComponent:ViewComponent
{
    private readonly MVCDbContext _context;

    public AddPeopleToCountryViewComponent(MVCDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
    int maxPriority, bool isDone)
    {
        ViewData["Customer"] = new SelectList(_context.Customer, "Id", "Name");
        ViewData["Country"] = new SelectList(_context.Country, "Id", "Id");
        return View();
    }
}
```

The Default.cshtml of ViewComponent

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label">People</label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Customer"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Country"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label">Comment</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="commentVchasno">
</div>
```

Instead of the PartialView in the modal of the main view

```
<div class="modal-body">
     @await Component.InvokeAsync("AddPeopleToCountry", new {  })
 </div>
```